# Firebase Rules permission denied but why?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This are my rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "freecoinsrequest":{
      ".read": false,
        ".write": "
      newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid 
       1. && (root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('/server/lasttimetookfreecoins').val() < now - 10000 
       2. || !root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('/server/lasttimetookfreecoins').exists())
       " ,
      "uid":{
        ".validate" : true
      },
        "$other":{
          ".write": false,
          ".validate": false
        }
    },
  }
}
```

So a user should only be able to write to the path if:

- the JSON contains "uid" as a key, and his uid as a value
- He did not write to server/lasttimetookfreecoins within 10 seconds ago OR
- He never wrote to server/lasttimetookfreecoins

I can not understand why it gets denied in the simulator. When I uncomment 1 and 2, as seen in the rules, it works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my testing, the rules produced the desired results when `/users/$uid/server/lasttimetookfreecoins` existed but failed when it did not.  Reversing the order of the conditions fixed that:

```
  newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid 
    && (!root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('/server/lasttimetookfreecoins').exists()
    || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('/server/lasttimetookfreecoins').val() < now - 10000)
```